# Catkin tools giving : "{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ros, catkin

Recently I installed catkin tools. I have ros (melodic) installed on my system (Ubuntu 18.04). The problem is that I can use catkin_init_workspace, but not catkin init. Using catkin_init or any of the commands of catkin tools gives me an error that asyncio is missing. So I installed asyncio using pip, but now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/comp/.local/bin/catkin", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('catkin-tools==0.4.5', 'console_scripts', 'catkin')()
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 28, in <module>
from catkin_tools.common import is_tty
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/common.py", line 24, in <module>
import asyncio
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asyncio/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from . import selectors
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asyncio/selectors.py", line 39
"{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is what I have done to get this error:

I just made a directory with a src directory in it and ran :

```
catkin init
```

Apparently catkin_init_workspace works fine.
Also, this is from where I followed instructions to install catkin tools:

https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html

This is the command I used to install asyncio:

```
pip uninstall asyncio
```

I get this error with catkin build too, where as catkin_make works fine (basically catkin tools are giving this error). I think this has got something to do with python version or something. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How did you install catkin tools? Which version of python/pip did you use for all of this? For ros melodic/ubuntu 18, it's still using/preferring system installs of packages and python packages, in py2. Did you run the `python setup.py develop`?

Comment: I installed catkin tools with these commands:   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu `lsb_release -sc` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'                                                                                    
$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -                                   $ sudo apt-get update                                                                                                                       
$ sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools
 @JWCS

Answer (score 0):

python2.7 is not supported, need python3. Refer to https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/386